# Using spyne, trying to produce a specific SOAP response with a XML attribute and a string value in the same element

Tags: python, python-3.x, soap, spyne

Using spyne to process and generate SOAP request/response. 
For a specific SOAP response, need to generate like

```
<SetSpecial tag="Monday">123</SetSpecial>
<SetSpecial tag="Tuesday">45</SetSpecial>
```

Could not get that exactly

Followed the tutorial of Spyne and also few almost similar posts, including [Spyne custom XML response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54362850/spyne-custom-xml-response)

Tried the below code......

```py
class CustomModel(ComplexModel):
    Value = String
    tag = XmlAttribute(Unicode)

## Then in actual view
response = Response()
response.SetSpecial([CustomModel(Value="123", tag="Monday"), CustomModel(Value="45", tag="Tuesday")])
```

Apart from ComplexModel could not get hands on any simple spyne Model to produce both an XML attribute and the string/integer primitive value in the same element.

Above response is a small portion in a bigger response. All other portions were well defined using Spyne's Complex Model. Only the mentioned part is not coming in the desired way.

Please provide any inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
class CustomModel(ComplexModel):
    Value = XmlData(Unicode)
    tag = XmlAttribute(Unicode)
```